# Mapping home key - supported all apps?

Tags: keyboard

I'm using the following technique to remap the home and end keys to make them work like windows:

```
~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict

{ /* Remap Home / End to be correct :-) */ 
"\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";                   /* Home         */ 
"\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";                         /* End          */ 
"$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Home */ 
"$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";       /* Shift + End  */ 
}
```

http://lifehacker.com/225873/mac-switchers-tip--remap-the-home-and-end-keys
(ie go to start and end of text row)

This doesn't appear to be supported in all apps (ie TextEdit)

Is there a different way to make this work in other mac apps? (ie is this technique obsolete on OS X Lion?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work in TextEdit and 10.7 / 10.8. Did you reopen applications after saving the plist? It looks valid, but you can check for syntax errors with `plutil ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.

DefaultKeyBinding.dict does not work in other applications like Xcode, Firefox, or Photoshop though. Another option would be to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/):

[image]

You can customize the setting group by copying it from [the source](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/for_pc_users.xml) to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lauri - could you clarify re the plist? Are you referring to the data structure in the .dict file?

Comment: Yeah, .dict is an alternative extension for .plist. The DefaultKeyBinding.dict in your question is an [old-style property list](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html).

Comment: Have you got an example of what a new-style mapping would look like?

Comment: It's just XML, like [this](https://github.com/hashrocket/dotmatrix/blob/master/custom/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict). Or I guess you could edit DefaultKeyBinding.dict with Xcode and save it as binary.